# Can I mirror changes in a database with homebrew code?

Tags: mysql, database, mirroring

I have several mysql databases and tables that need to be "listened to".  I need to know what data changes and send the changes to remote servers that have local mirrors of the database.

How can I mirror changes in the mysql databases? I was thinking of setting up mysql triggers that write all changes to another table. This table has the database name, table name, and all of the columns. I'd then write custom code to transfer the changes and install them periodically on the remote mirrors. Will this accomplish my need?

Comment: As the current answers demonstrate, using a mechanism outside of a DBMS to handle a DB task like replication is guaranteed to be broken.

Comment: @msw how is my answer broken? It's *not* outside of the DB.

Comment: @jterrace The question as posed was broken, as it was attempting to use a non-DB mechanism to accomplish the task. I've edited the question to more accurately reflect the semantics of what was being described.

Comment: @msw sure, but my answer is *not* broken. It's a perfectly valid way to do replication, using the DB mechanisms itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is 100% correct.

That extra table is called an "audit" or "history" table (there are subtle distinctions but you shouldn't much care - but you now have the "official" terms which you can use to do further research).

If the main table has columns A, B, C, then the audit would have 3 more: A, B, C, Operation, Changed_By, Change_DateTime (names are subject to your tastes and coding standards).

"Operation" column stores whether the change was an insert, delete, old value of update or new value of update (frequently it's 3 characters wide and the operations as "INS"/"DEL"/"U_D" and "U_I", but there are other approaches).

The data in the audit table is populated via a trigger on the main table.

Then make sure there's an index on Change_DateTime column.

And to find a list of changes, you keep track of when you last polled, and then simply do

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Audit WHERE Change_DateTime > 'LAST_POLL_TIME'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell MySQL to create an incremental backup from a specific point in time. The data contains only the changes to the database since that time.

You have to turn on binary logging and then you can use the `mysqlbinlog` command to export the changes since a given timestamp. See the [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/point-in-time-recovery.html) section of the manual as well as the [documentation for mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html). Specifically, you will want the [--start-datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-datetime) parameter.

Once you have the exported log in text format, you can execute it on another database instance.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you step outside the mechanisms of the DBMS to accomplish an inherently DB oriented task like mirroring, you've violated most of the properties of a DB that distinguish it from an ordinary file.

In particular, the mechanism you propose violates the [atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) that MySQL is built to ensure. For example, incomplete playback of the log on the mirrors will leave your mirrors in a state inconsistent with the parent DB. What you propose can only approximate mirroring, thus you should prefer DBMS intrinsic mechanisms unless you don't care if the mirrors accurately reflect the state of the parent.